# jQuery - Find img element with dashed border amongst list

Tags: jquery

I have a list of images in a table like so:

```
<div id="scroll-uploader-photos">
<table>
<tr>
    <td><img class="uploader_thumbs" style="border:solid 3px grey;"></td>
    <td><img class="uploader_thumbs" style="border:solid 3px grey;"></td>
    <td><img class="uploader_thumbs" style="border:solid 3px grey;"></td>
    <td><img class="uploader_thumbs" style="border:solid 3px grey;"></td>
    <td><img class="uploader_thumbs" style="border:dashed 3px red;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Using jQuery 1.7.1, how can I select the image element that has the dashed border?

Am I right in saying I need to loop through elements using .find() or similar and test each item in loop for a CSS attribute "border:dashed 3px red"? Is this right way or is there an easier way?

Help and suggestions always gratefully received.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate over the images and check the css.

```
$(".uploader_thumbs").each(function() {
    if($(this).css('border') == '3px dashed rgb(255, 0, 0)')
        console.log(this)
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twMSG/4/)

Honestly though, I would apply a class to each element instead of doing it inline and then select items with that class. [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/twMSG/5/)

Comment: Aaaah, okay, thanks a bunch. Is there a reason why you used RGB values instead of HEX or color?

Comment: That's how jQuery displays it in dev tools and since we're doing a string comparison that's how I have it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you don't need to loop explicitly - use [.filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$('table').find('img').filter(function() { 
   return $(this).css('borderStyle') === 'dashed';
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qAht3/) to play with.

But technically it's still a loop, so you're probably right. )

Comment: +1 Did not know about `.filter()`! I want to say this might be better as there might be some optimization done in the jQuery code, but I don't know.